# Error when assigning tempfile.TemporaryFile to a variable and executing

Tags: python

So let's say that my class looks like the below, with all relevant imports already done:

```
class LargeRequest(server.Request):
    memory_limit = 1024*1024*25
    temp_type = tempfile.TemporaryFile

    def parse_multipart(self, fp, pdict):
        while loop_condition:
            if self.temp_type.__name__ == 'SpooledTemporaryFile':
                data = self.temp_type(max_size=self.memory_limit)
            else:
                data = self.temp_type()
            ...
            data.write('stuff')
```

When I run this I get an error:

```
  File "/home/user/workspace/twisted/server.py", line 226, in parse_multipart
    data = self.temp_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 484, in TemporaryFile
    if 'b' in mode:
exceptions.TypeError: argument of type 'instance' is not iterable
```

Which refers to [this line in tempfile.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/tempfile.py#l448).

Also, this error does not occur when I simply do:

```
data = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
```

But I would like a bit more flexibility. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temp_type` become instance method. `self.temp_type()` call become `TemporaryFile(self)`.

Try following:

```
temp_type = staticmethod(tempfile.TemporaryFile)
```